# How to add a row to dataframe without changing col classes?

Tags: r, rbind

I have a dataframe of 5 observations of 15 variables. Some of the classes are character, some numeric, some integer. I am trying to add a new row to my data frame. I did this by creating a new row:

```
newrow= c('Chiyoda',600,.08,2,1500,1,3000,6500,10, .65, .1, 0,0,0,0)
```

and then rbinding it to my data frame:

```
mydata = rbind(mydata,newrow)
```

the problem is that when I do the rbind it changes the classes of every column in my data frame to character and I can't do operations on them the way I could when they were numeric. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve writing out the class of every element?

Thanks

Comment: use `newrow <- list(...)` instead since you cannot mix types in vectors

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to define `newrow` like this:

```
newrow= list('Chiyoda',600,.08,2,1500,1,3000,6500,10, .65, .1, 0,0,0,0)
```

because when you concatenate numeric and character variables together using `c()`, R will coerce the numeric variables to character and return a character vector.